# NullPointerException when running JUnit tests, saying interface is null

Tags: java, interface, junit, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to write a java program that allows the user to input a series of data values then for the program to sort through finding the mean and the median of that series, using an interface to "treat" different objects as if they were the same.  However when I run my JUnit test, it keeps saying my interface is null.

NoiseFilter.java

```
package noisefilter.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface NoiseFilter {

public double getBestMesurement(ArrayList<Double> samples);

}
```

AveragingFilter.java

```
package noisefilter.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AveragingFilter implements NoiseFilter {

@Override
/**
 * The method getBestMeasurement takes an array list of type double and returns a
 */
public double getBestMesurement(ArrayList<Double> samples) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (samples.equals(null)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Samples cannot be null");
    }
    if (samples.size() < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Sample size must have 3");
    }
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (Double number : samples) {
        sum += number;
    }

    return (sum / samples.size());
}

}
```

SensorData.java

```
package noisefilter.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SensorData implements NoiseFilter {

ArrayList<Double> data;
NoiseFilter filter;

public SensorData() {
    this.data = new ArrayList<Double>();
    this.filter = null;
}

public void addSample(double sample) {
    data.add(sample);
}

public void setFilter(NoiseFilter filterVar) {
    this.filter = filterVar;
}

public double getFilteredResult() {
    if (filter.equals(null)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The filter cannot be left null");
    }
    return filter.getBestMesurement(data);
}

@Override
public double getBestMesurement(ArrayList<Double> samples) {

    samples = this.data;
    return 0;
}
```

WhenAveragingFilter.java (JUnit Test)

```
package noisefilter.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import noisefilter.model.NoiseFilter;
import noisefilter.model.SensorData;

public class WhenAverageFiltering {

NoiseFilter filter;
SensorData dataSet;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.dataSet = new SensorData();
    dataSet.setFilter(filter);
}

@Test
public void averageOfThree100sShouldBe100() {
    dataSet.addSample(100);
    dataSet.addSample(100);
    dataSet.addSample(100);

    assertTrue(dataSet.getFilteredResult() == 100);
}

@Test
public void averageOfThreeDifferent() {
    dataSet.addSample(120);
    dataSet.addSample(140);
    dataSet.addSample(130);

    assertTrue(dataSet.getFilteredResult() == 130);
}

@Test
public void averageOfFiveDifferent() {
    dataSet.addSample(10);
    dataSet.addSample(50);
    dataSet.addSample(60);

    assertTrue(dataSet.getFilteredResult() == 40);
}

}
```

Here's the errors that I get when I run the JUnit Test.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at noisefilter.model.SensorData.getFilteredResult(SensorData.java:24)
at     noisefilter.tests.WhenAverageFiltering.averageOfFiveDifferent(WhenAverageFiltering.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialize the `filter` field in the test class

```
NoiseFilter filter;
SensorData dataSet;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.dataSet = new SensorData();
    dataSet.setFilter(filter);
}
```

so it is `null` here and that reference propagates to the `SensorData` object you are testing.

```
public void setFilter(NoiseFilter filterVar) {
    this.filter = filterVar;
}
```

`filterVar` is `null` when you call the above.

You have to initialize it with an implementation of your interface, such as your `AveragingFilter`:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.filter = new AveragingFilter(); // or something like it
    this.dataSet = new SensorData();
    dataSet.setFilter(filter);
}
```

Also, you are testing for null in a few places using this pattern:

```
if( x.equals( null ) ) {...
```

This will not work, because this is calling the `equals(Object)` method on the object `x`. In Java, `null` does not have any methods. You always have to check for null against its *identity*, using the `==` operator. Your examples should read:

```
if( x == null ) { ...
```

Comment: I tried the this.filter = new NoiseFilter(); and since it's an interface, not a type, I got an error saying cannot instantiate type.  I don't know how to initialize an interface directly.

Comment: @DannyBurkhart I could not know it was an interface. You cannot instantiate interfaces. Do you have a class that implements that interface? If so initialize it with that. If not, create one (possibly as an anonymous class.

Comment: There's an implementation of the interface in the question, so you do want this.filter = new AveragingFilter();. There's also another error with null-checking; I'll see if I can edit the answer.

Comment: @Calum Thanks, I missed that. Propose an edit. I'll review and accept.

Comment: @Dan Check the edit. You already have an implementation of `NoiseFilter` in the form of `AveragingFilter`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You were way ahead of me with that edit, but I've added in the note about null checks.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  I fixed this NPE problem.  Now, my program won't implement all getBestMeasurement methods.  When I run it, it only runs the one from the sensor data class which returns 0.  Any help from guys smarter than me? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dan That is another question entirely. Consider creating a new SO question. You haven't provided any details either. Don't ever make any assumptions on SO.

Comment: Thanks @SoritosDelimanolis.  I figured it out, but thank you and Calum for all your help.  :D

Comment: @Dan Considering accepting one of the answers if everything you asked was covered.

Answer (score 1):

Your setUp()method does not create a filter.

It creates an instance of SensorData and then passes a null value to setFilter.
When getFilteredResult() is called later on it runs into a NPE.

Added after commenting:

Anonymous class:

```
filter = new NoiseFilter() {
    public double getBestMesurement(ArrayList<Double> samples) {
        return 100; // or do something else
    }
}

dataSet.setFilter(filter);
```

with Mockito:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*

// ...

filter = Mockito.mock( NoiseFilter.class );
when( filter.getBestMesurement( anyListOf( Double.class ) ) ).thenReturn( 100.0 )

dataSet.setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: How can I initialize the filter?  Or assign a value to it?  This is my first time working with an interface.

Comment: If you just want to test that the call to `getFilteredResult` calles the filter, than either use an anonymous class (like Sotirios Delimanolis suggested above) or look into mocking frameworks like Mockito.